# Facebook Graph Api new feed filter

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Calling graph.facebook.com/me/home and it's returning valid results.

However, it's not the same as the one I have on facebook. Since my main feed is being filtered by the people I interact with most.

What I'm asking is if there is a way to get the same filtering on this feed.

Answer (score 1):

Use an FQL query on `stream` with a `stream_filter`:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/

```
SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, message
FROM stream
WHERE filter_key in (
    SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid=me() AND type='newsfeed'
)
AND is_hidden = 0
```

The `is_hidden` doesn't seem to make and difference though. Also, read this:
http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=45819